# How to get every RootID in a multi model scenario? | Forge Viewer API

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Currently im trying to get the values of a specific property from all objects from every model. E.g. I need to get the value from the property "layer" from all Objects, so that I can automatically create a list to filter the models by.
I already managed to print all the distinct propertys and its values, but only from the first model that was loaded in.

In this code segment I iterate over all the loaded models and then, for every model, I iterate over the search values. These values are predefined and would e.g. be 'layer'.
After that, using the model instance, i retrieve its object tree. And using this object tree I get the root id.

```
async function getTreefromObject() {
    var modelInstance;
    var objectTree;
    var rootId;
    for(var urn of loadedModels) {
        for(var filterValue of FILTER_VALUES) {
            modelInstance = loadedModels[urn];
            console.log(urn);
            console.log(filterValue);
            objectTree = await new Promise((resolve)=> {
                modelInstance.getObjectTree(function(objectTree) {
                    resolve(objectTree);
                })
            });
            rootId = objectTree.getRootId();
            console.log('RootID: ', rootId);
            await extractAttributesRecursively(rootId, filterValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the root id is always the same (1), even though the object tree is different for every model.

As i noticed this I tried to get the model id using
`viewer.model.getInstanceTree()`
and manually input these , so that the function would use these numbers instead of the root id.

But this also didnt work because the following function kept searching only the model that was first loaded in.

This recursive function first gets the properties from the provided dbId. then, if it found some properties, it continues to try to find the specified property ('layer'). When successful the value gets added to my value matrix, if not then the function gets deeper into the object tree.

```
async function extractAttributesRecursively(dbId, filterValue, depth = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        viewer.getProperties(dbId, function(properties) {
            if (properties ) {
                const levelAttribute = properties.properties.find(prop => prop.displayName === filterValue);
                if (levelAttribute) {
                    if (!valueMatrix[filterValue]) {
                        valueMatrix[filterValue] = [];
                    }
                    valueMatrix[filterValue].push(levelAttribute.displayValue);
                } else if (depth < MAX_RECURSION_DEPTH){
                    viewer.model.getInstanceTree().enumNodeChildren(dbId, function(childId) {
                        extractAttributesRecursively(childId, filterValue, depth+1);
                    });
                }
            }
            resolve();    
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: After lots of trying I concluded that my main problem is, that the dbIds do not seem to be unique in a multimodel scenario. On the other hand, the built in property browser works fine. So there must be a way!

Answer (score 0):

Found the error!

I had to hand over the **modelInstance** to `extractAttributesRecursively()` and then instead of

`viewer.getProperties(dbId, function(properties)`

it is just

`modelInstance.getProperties(dbId, function(properties)`